# How to get an array from the controller using struts, JSP and Java

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts2, jstl

I want to know if anyone here knows how to get an array from a controller using Struts?

**showTeams.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="nl.***.controller.TeamController"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@include file="includes/layout.jsp" %>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1>Alle Teams</h1>
    <table>
        <caption><h1>List of Teams</h1></caption>
        <th>ID Team</th>
        <th>Naam Team</th>
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="team" items="${teams}">
                <td>${team.getId}<td>
                <td>${team.getName()}<td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<a href="index.jsp">Back to Start</a>
<%@include file="includes/footer.jsp" %>
```

**TeamController.java**

```
package nl.***.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import nl.***.datalayer.DAOTeam;
import nl.***.models.Team;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class TeamController extends ActionSupport{
    private String name;
    ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

    public String execute() throws Exception{
        return "createTeam";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String addTeamToDB(String name){
        try{
            Team t = new Team(name);
            DAOTeam.getInstance().createTeam(t);
            return "<h1>Team " + name + " is toegevoegd aan de Database</h1>";
        }catch(Exception e){
        return "<h1>FAILED with message" + e.getMessage() + "</h1>"; 
        }
    }

    public String getAllTeams(){
        teams = DAOTeam.getInstance().loadTeams();
        System.out.println("ik ben er!!@#!EWDSRETGDFQTWTRE"); //for testing, removed when done
        //mapping.findForward("showTeams");
        return "getallteams";
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
    <package name="teamcreate" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="createTeam" 
            class="controller.TeamController" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="createTeam">/view/prossesTeam.jsp</result>
      </action>
    </package>
    <package name="teamLoad" extends="struts-default">
          <action name="showTeams" 
            class="controller.TeamController" 
            method="getallteams">
            <result name="getallteams">/view/showTeams.jsp</result>

      </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

When I load the page it does not have the array 'teams' defined in the controller. I've tried changing values in `struts.xml` but still nothing. If tried to make an if statement in the execute function in `TeamController` to make sure it even ran but I got nothing I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**:
What I essentially want is that when you go to `showTeams.jsp`, it should show you a table with all the teams using Struts.

Comment: You can use `struts iterator` tag too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view should be returned from the controller with the result `getallteams`. So you should call `showTeams` action to load teams into the action class variable.

```java
private List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

public List<Team> getTeams() { return teams; };
```

The last method is required to evaluate `teams` in the `forEach` tag

```jsp
<c:forEach var="team" items="${teams}">
    <td>${team.id}<td>
    <td>${team.name}<td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks I indeed forgot to make an getTeams() function in the controller it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do any struts for the last 5 years, so I'm not sure about your controller, but if you copy/paste your code of the JSP, then you have some syntax problem.

```
<td>${team.getId}<td>
<td>${team.getName()}<td>
```

getId / getName()  => one with brackets, one without ? 
And you should not use the name of the getter but the property. 
Like :

```
<td>${team.id}<td>
<td>${team.name}<td>
```

If the syntax is correct, you should at least get an empty array (just the headers).